# How to derive ~ ( P&Q) from ~ P using natural deduction?

Tags: propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

Certainly if P is false, (P&Q) cannot be true.

But how to prove this using natural deduction?

I'd propose as a direct proof the following derivation :

(1) ~P    ( Premise )

(2) ~P v ~Q  ( v - intro)

(3) ~ ( P & Q)  ( DeMorgan)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) $\lnot P$ --- premise

2) $(P \land Q)$ --- assumed [a]

3) $P$ --- from 2) by $(\land \text E)$

4) $\bot$ --- from 1) and 2), by [$(\lnot \text E)$](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) (alternatively, using $(\to \text E)$, if $\lnot P$ is defined as $P \to \bot$)

> 5) $\lnot (P \land Q)$ --- from 2) and 4) by $(\lnot \text I)$, discharging [a].